# Is it possible to manually run a build on a local Azure build agent without a DevOps server?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We normally use on-premises Azure DevOps Server to maange our build pipelines, using YML files. We have build agents running on one or more build servers.

A specific piece of R&D would be made far easier if we could install VS and a build-agent on a standalone box which is *not* linked to the Azure DevOps server, and manually 'run an YML build' against the build agent locally.
We don't have access to DevOps server from this machine and the alternative is rescripting an alternative to our YML in Powerscript or similar.

Is there any realistic way to do this?

Comment: Trying to understand your question... Are you referring to the on-prem solution Azure DevOps Server? If yes, have you considered Azure DevOps Services and Self-hosted agents? I'm not an expert but I do use DevOps services extensively and I'm not sure if I understand correctly and if my use-case applies to yours.

Comment: @KedMardemootoo I've reworded to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to manually run a build on a local Azure build agent without a DevOps server?

I am afraid there is no such way to manually run a build on a local Azure build agent without a DevOps server.

That's because azure devops services/server is equivalent to an interpreter and trigger. Agent itself is not a program that can be executed independently like MSBuild.exe, it does not have the ability to parse YAML grammar, it can only execute the parsed command passed by the server.

I totally understand your needs and approve of it, so I recommend you add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions：

[image]